# Connection is invalid in connection pooling

Tags: java, jdbc, c3p0

I am using c3p0 for connection poolingin my java application. We write the all properties related to it and i am having wait_timeout value is 60. We can not increase wait_timeout value. I got error "connection is invalid". How to handle this error.

Comment: The word is 'pooling '. 'Polling' is something quite different,

Comment: You should add clarifications on your question. What are the exact properties you used? What is the exact error you experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should set max_idle_time for waiting timeout ; for example :

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">50</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">15</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_idle_time">60</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">10</property>
```

see this link : http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#configuration_files

you can find same question in stack overflow fro example :

[Hibernate c3p0 connection pool not timing out idle connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375074/hibernate-c3p0-connection-pool-not-timing-out-idle-connections)

[c3p0 maxIdleTime is same as wait_timeout of mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24565274/c3p0-maxidletime-is-same-as-wait-timeout-of-mysql)

Comment: what configuration use when wait_ timeout is 28800?